# Troubles installing TelnetClient

Tags: powershell, installation, addremoveprograms

From an administrator PowerShell prompt:

```
PS> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName TelnetClient

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The referenced assembly could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName TelnetClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

It also reports a similar error if I try to do it through "Programs and Features".

Comment: Is your platform supported?  i.e. are you using PowerShell x86 when it's expecting x64, or something of that nature?

Comment: This likely means that the TelnetClient isn't correct in the Component Based Service store. I would start by running `sfc /scannow` and then `DISM.exe /Image:c:\offline /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:c:\example\mount` against known good media

Comment: This isn't a programming or even a PowerShell issue. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) would be a more appropriate place for this question.